# How do I bring back an entire range of dates in SQL between two dates, even when there is no data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to get the number of incidents in my database, in the format:

```
date   numberOfIncidents
date   numberOfIncidents
date   numberOfIncidents
date   numberOfIncidents
```

I supply the start date / end date to my SQL stored procedure, but if there is no entry in the database for a particular date (because no incidents occured) then I wont get the full range back.

What I want is every single date to be returned between my start/end dates, with a value next to it.

Is this possible in SQL Server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a recursive [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to produce the date range and then join it to your incidents.

```
WITH DateRange(date) AS
(
  SELECT @dateFrom date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, date) date FROM DateRange WHERE date < @dateTo
)

SELECT DateRange.date, count(incident.id) 
FROM DateRange
LEFT OUTER JOIN incident
  ON incident.date >= DateRange.date 
  AND incident.date < DATEADD(dd, 1, DateRange.date)
GROUP BY DateRange.date
ORDER BY DateRange.date
```

By default, SQL Server limits the recursive definition to 100 rows. If you need more than 100 date rows, append `OPTION (MAXRECURSION n)` to the end of the query, changing `n` to the required number of rows.

Comment: I've been just staring at this for five whole minutes, marvelling at the level of magic...

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to tell without more information, but it sounds like what you need to do is create a temp table that has your complete date range in it, then use a left join to join it to your numberOfIncidents data.  Then you'll get all the dates, even if there were no incidents.

**EDIT:** To create the temp table, you could just create a loop that goes from your startDate to your endDate, and insert those rows into the db.

Try this code:

```
-- These dates are just for example purposes
declare @startDate datetime
declare @endDate datetime
set @startDate = '2009-11-20'
set @endDate = '2009-12-17'


while @startDate < @endDate
    begin
        -- This line is where you insert into your temp table.  I'm just
        -- printing the value out, so you can se what's happening.
        print @startDate
        -- Go to the next day.
        set @startdate = dateadd(dd, 1, @startdate)
    end
```

Comment: Can you explain how I can do that? The part where I basically create a temp table of dates from the supplied date range. Once I can figure that out it's probably ok.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can use a [Numbers Table](http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/tblnumbers.aspx) a bit like this (probably not overly efficient, and assumes incident dates have zero time parts (00:00:00) - if this is not true you'll need to make the time zero test the difference in dates):

```
CREATE PROC dbo.GetRange @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime
AS BEGIN
     -- Setting up a numbers table...
    WITH Nbrs_3( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 0 ),
    Nbrs_2( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_3 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_3 n2 ),
    Nbrs_1( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_2 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_2 n2 ),
    Nbrs_0( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_1 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_1 n2 ),
    Nbrs ( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_0 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_0 n2 ),
    N AS (SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) FROM Nbrs ),
     -- Getting the full date range
    DateRange AS (  SELECT thedate = DATEADD(day,N.n-1,@startdate)
            FROM N
            WHERE N.n <= DATEDIFF(day,@startdate,@enddate)+1  )
    SELECT D.thedate
         , numincidents = (SELECT count(*) 
                          FROM TBL_INCIDENTS I 
                          WHERE I.incdate = D.thedate)
    FROM DateRange D 
    GROUP BY D.thedate

END
GO
```

Then use as..

```
exec GetRange @startdate = {d '2009-02-01'},  @enddate = {d '2009-03-31'}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this (admittedly this isn't a stored procedure, but it should be useful):

```
DECLARE @start_date datetime,
        @end_date   datetime

SELECT @start_date = '2009-12-01', @end_date = '2009-12-31'

DECLARE @d datetime
SET @d = @start_date
WHILE @d < dateadd(d, 1, @end_date)
BEGIN
  PRINT @d
  SET @d = dateadd(d, 1, @d)
END
```

Comment: Very similar to what I wrote...so obviously you must be on the right track!  ;)  +1.