# SQL joining with parameter problem

Tags: sql-server

I asked this question before:

[How do I bring back an entire range of dates in SQL between two dates, even when there is no data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921818/how-do-i-bring-back-an-entire-range-of-dates-in-sql-between-two-dates-even-when)

but I now need to only select incidents that have a Status of "E" for emergency.

I can't put WHERE status='E' though, because that will stop it returning an entry for every single date.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add it to the `LEFT OUTER JOIN ... ON`, since this is a contition for the joined rows as far as I understand the question.

Something like this:

```
WITH DateRange(date) AS (
    SELECT @dateFrom dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, date) date FROM DateRange WHERE date < @dateTo
)
SELECT DateRange.date, count(incident.id) 
FROM DateRange
LEFT OUTER JOIN incident
    ON incident.date >= DateRange.date 
    AND incident.date < DATEADD(dd, 1, DateRange.date)
    AND incident.status = 'E'
GROUP BY DateRange.date
ORDER BY DateRange.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said in your question, putting the condition in your WHERE clause effectively turns your LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN.

You should add this to your LEFT JOIN criteria as the intent is that it's a condition of the join.

So something like table1

```
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.field = table2.field AND table1.status='E'
```